# Use generic type of one object as type information for another in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have a class of type

```
IDType<IDDataType>
```

and another class of type

```
SelectionManager<IDDataType>
```

Is there a way that I can infer the data type for objects of the second class by passing an instance of the first one? Something like that

```
IDType<String> idType = new IDType<String>();
SelectionManager<idType.getGenericType()> selectionManager = new Se.....
```

Of course, the reason I want to do this is that idType (String is an example here) is created in totally unrelated places.

Comment: How about declaring `SelectionManager<IDType<T>>` instead, so you have `T` directly?

Comment: Hmm, I can do something like:   `SelectionManager<IDTypeType extends IDType<IDDataType>, IDDataType>`
But what do I tell the constructor of SelectionManager?

Comment: Thanks everyone, and sorry for the unclear question...
It turns out to be possible as suggested by Grouchal and Peter Lawrey, but for my case this won't work because the parts of the code are to disconnected and to much effort to adapt right now. 

What I was looking for was, as Karsten Daemen said, in fact impossible due to type erasure. I will use a solution that uses Integers instead of generic data types (requires more memory though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no elegant way in java to do something like:

```
IDType<String> idType = new IDType<String>();
idType.getGenericType();
```

This is because the Java compiler does not know the type of the object at runtime. Read the part about "Type erasure" on the wikipedia page of "[Generics in Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java)". Java was initially not designed to work with these.

You could always use some dirty hacks though ... instanceof can do the job but that is ugly programming.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare extra generics in each methods.

```
 public <T> void method() {
      IDType<T> idType = new IDType<T>();
      SelectionManager<T> selectionManager = new SelectionManager<T>();
```

Comment: That won't work in my case because there is no one to pass along the information. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If the information isn't passed in any way, you have nothing to check.  You may as well make it non-generic, except you can make it that the types match.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a bit hard to understand in the way that you have written the example because you want someone who calls your code to define the Types but that is not how your example is written.

As the code is at the moment you could make it non-generic and it would make no difference because at compile time your code has all the type information.

For your example to work there has to be a code snippet A (written by someone else) where an IDType is defined and then passed to the code you have written (snippet B):

```
IDType<String> idType  = new IDType<String>();
YourClass.yourMethod(idType);
```

Snippet B (your code) would then look something like this:

```
public <T> void yourMethod(IDType<T> idType){
    SelectionManager<T> selectionManager = new SelectionManager<T>();
}
```

This means that selectionManager would have the same genericType as idType.

Hope this makes sense!